# How long does it take to see Google Play revenue?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

My app is available since a few days for google play now.
I know that I got a few In-App-Purchases since that time, but I can’t see any of them in my developer console.

How long does it take until I can see my revenue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it takes 24 hours, but you can check `Order management` from Google Play console to see purchases before they appear on the app dashboard.

[image]